# How to check if I'm already subscribed to parse.com push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

How I can check if I'm already subscribed on a pase.com push notification channel? I have this code on Oncreate method, but this code subscribe the app every time it's executed, I want to subscribe only if it's necessary

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "iDVqFBKpbYtSRGzeU06WGjDuaCRKOPoCQW9wtdLc", "9Hl628QThttuR8UwidCPijyKZwUdvc4w384Cv522");
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far (as far as checking your subscription is concerned)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because i haven't found nothing in the API

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions to channels are tracked in your Installation object. You can check if the current install is subscribed to a channel by checking the "channels" array in `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getJSONArray("channels")`.

Comment: I get and empty JSONArray, I'am not sure how it works you must suscribe every time  the application starts or you are already subscripted once you execute the application for first time?.